# How do I change a date in 19950428 to 4/28/1995 in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data as show below in excel with column F having a different date format yyyymmdd as text.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0ceS.png)

For example **19900216**. I need it to be in this format **2/16/1990**

Any help I could would be appreciated.

Comment: I also found **Fill Flash** which worked as well. 
I typed the format I prefered the output to look and used a *Fill Flash** to arrive at the same results.

I am grateful to the community for all the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends if you want it converting to a date value (so you can base other cell formulas on it) or just as a text string.

Text String:
`=RIGHT(A1, 2) & "/" & MID(A1, 5, 2) & "/" & LEFT(A1, 4)`

Date Value:
`=DATE(LEFT(A1, 4), MID(A1, 5, 2), RIGHT(A1, 2))` then change the cell number formatting to get the desired date format.

(where `A1` is the cell to be converted)

Answer (score 3):

you can use Excel's "Text To Columns" feature to achieve your required outcome. I have linked an article below that shows how to use the Text To Columns feature to convert the dates, however, if that article doesn't help you, I'm sure you will be able to find more articles online.

https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/6-ways-to-fix-dates-formatted-as-text-in-excel